# Copy and paste a range from each worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that contains oil production information for oil wells. Each well has its own worksheet.I want to copy and paste the cumulative oil and gas production from each well into a preformated worksheet at the end of the workbook so i can get a list of the cumulative oil production.

The normal copy and paste vba isn't working for me because what I am trying to paste is a calculated value. Whenever I execute my current code, I get the #REF error.

I know this is not a unique question and that it has been asked before on here. I have looked at previous answers to this question though and tried to cannibalize the code but have failed. I know that I need to use the paste special function, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get this to work either.

I am copying the range AB3:AE3. The sheet name I am trying to copy and paste into is SmtProd. I want the values to be copied into the SmtProd sheet starting at row 2 (row 1 has the headers).

Below is my current copy and paste code

```
Range("AB3:AE3").Copy
  Selection.Copy Sheets("SmtProd").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Josiah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub MakeSummary()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, N As Long
    Dim i As Long, M As Long
    N = Sheets.Count - 1
    M = 2
    For i = 1 To N
        Sheets(i).Range("AB3:AE3").Copy
        Sheets("SmtProd").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("SmtProd").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
        M = M + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note the double-paste.

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much. I have been stuck on this for a day.